# Function failed why?

Tags: r, function

```
file_1<-function(x)
  {
  x<-data.frame(x)
  for(i in 1:ncol(x))
    {
    if(class(x[ , i])=="character"){
      x<-factor(x[, i])
    }
  }
  par(mfrow=c(ceiling(ncol(x)/2),2))
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)){ 
    if(class(x[,i])=="factor")
      plot(x[, i], xlab=paste(colnames(x[i])))
  }
  else if(class(x[ ,i]=="numeric") {
    hist(x[ , i] , main=NULL, xlab=paste(colnames(x[, i])))
  }
}

}
```

x is a file, the function data.frames and factors the file  and makes plots and histograms

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the meaning of "_the function data.frames and factors the file_"? Should this function read some data from a file `x`? If not so, what is `x`? Is it a string, double, integer, or an R object?

Comment: yes this function should read some data from a file x

Comment: Then what kind of file is `x`? Is it a csv file? Note that `data.frame` does not read data from `x`. It is used in R to create a data.frame. You need to look for functions with this pattern `read.*`

Comment: x is an excel file and my teacher used data.frame so i don't know

Comment: Please consider providing more debugging details. 1) The file extension of `x`. `x` can be opened in excel does not mean it is an excel file. 2) One picture that shows what `x` looks like exactly. 3) Perhaps share your data for us to test.

Comment: I don't have a real file, x is a hypothetical file which  is inserted in this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have braces and parens out of place. Namely,

```r
  for(i in 1:ncol(x)){ 
    if(class(x[,i])=="factor")
      plot(x[, i], xlab=paste(colnames(x[i])))
  }
  else if(class(x[ ,i]=="numeric") {
    hist(x[ , i] , main=NULL, xlab=paste(colnames(x[, i])))
  }
```

The inner problem is that `if(class(x[ ,i]=="numeric")` should instead be `if(class(x[ ,i])=="numeric")`.

The outer problem is that with your `{...}` braces, you are attempting `for (...) { ... } else { ... }`. I believe your `else` is meant to be inside the `for` loop, after the `if`.

Try this as a literal fix to the parsing errors.

```r
file_1 <- function(x) {
  x <- data.frame(x)
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)) {
    if (class(x[ , i]) == "character"){
      x <- factor(x[, i])
    }
  }
  par(mfrow = c(ceiling(ncol(x)/2), 2))
  for (i in 1:ncol(x)){
    if (class(x[,i]) == "factor") {
      plot(x[, i], xlab = paste(colnames(x[i])))
    } else if (class(x[ ,i]) == "numeric") {
      hist(x[ , i] , main = NULL, xlab = paste(colnames(x[, i])))
    }
  }
}
```

Perhaps accept this altered version:

```r
file_1 <- function(x) {
  ischr <- sapply(x, is.character)
  x[ischr] <- lapply(x[ischr], factor)
  par(mfrow = c(ceiling(ncol(x)/2), 2))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (is.factor(x[,i])) {
      plot(x[,i], xlab = colnames(x)[i])
    } else {
      hist(x[,i], main = NULL, xlab = colnames(x)[i])
    }
  }
}
```